# How to change comboBox items if i checked radioButton using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-5.0

if i choose radio Button the combo box items change.

if i choose another radio Button the combo box item change .

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("google");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("yahoo");
    }
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in same group, you can do this just by adding listener to one of them:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioButton_1.Checked)
    {
         comboBox1.Items.Remove("google");
         comboBox1.Items.Add("yahoo");
    }
    else
    {
         comboBox1.Items.Remove("yahoo");
         comboBox1.Items.Add("google");
    }
}
```